# Wilcoxon tests in Doronix Math Toolbox

Tags: p-value, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I'm using Doronix Math Toolbox. They have statistical functions (http://www.doronix.com/statistics.html). I can't figure out how they are finding p-value in ranksum and signsum tests. Does anyone know it? I'm asking because answer is different than in MATLAB. But answer in MATLAB is different than is SPSS. Can I use Doronix Math Toolbox Wilcoxon tests?

Answer (score 2):

Well if they don't explain in the documentation of Doronix Math Toolbox, you can't be sure how they calculate the p-value. All statistical packages explain either in their documentation or their outputs how they calculate the p-value. See:

- R [wilcox.test](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/wilcox.test.html)
- Matlab [ranksum](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/ranksum.html#bti4z5t)
- Stata [ranksum](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rranksum.pdf#page=4)
- SPSS [Mann-Whitney test](http://facstaff.cbu.edu/~wschrein/media/Stat/SPSS%2019%20Manual.pdf#page=42)

So, if you want to use some software's function to do that, you should know how it does it. Otherwise, you could calculate it on your own.